# Как вытянуть токен с storage cookie?

Tags: axios, auth, jwt

Как вытянуть `jwt token` с с **storage/cookies** и отправить заново на сервер?

пробовал примерно вот так, но не получилось

```
const token = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('data'));
const token = data._auth_t; 

      const config = {
    headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` }
};

const bodyParameters = {
   key: "value"
};

axios.post( 
  'https://HIDELINK/admin/users?offset=0&count=21&query=34&orderBy=asc',
  bodyParameters,
  config
).then(console.log).catch(console.log);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Так из storage или из cookie? Это совершенно разные вещи

Comment: Из куков,желательно без либы

Answer (score 0):

Использовал библиотеку **js-cookie**

```
import Cookies from 'js-cookie'

const authToken = Cookies.get('_auth_t');
axios.interceptors.request.use((config) => {
  config.headers.authorization = `Bearer ${authToken}`;
  return config;
});
```